# Does the pessimistic meta-induction say that best scientific theories may be untrue, or merely not true about reality?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Does the [pessimistic meta-induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pessimistic_induction) say that best scientific theories may be untrue, or merely not true about a mind independent reality? Might examples from the history of science of past refuted theories show that there are no quarks, or only that there are no real quarks? Either for Lauden, or as a reasonable extension of the argument (in anti-realist literature).

[Anti-realists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-realism/#AntiFoilForScieReal) can say we have no knowledge of unobservables

> The term “antirealism” (or “anti-realism”) encompasses any position
>   that is opposed to realism along one or more of the dimensions
>   canvassed in section 1.2: the metaphysical commitment to the existence
>   of a mind-independent reality; the semantic commitment to interpret
>   theories literally or at face value; and the epistemological
>   commitment to regard theories as furnishing knowledge of both
>   observables and unobservables.

But it seems to me like a particularly strong form of anti-realism, to deny we have any knowledge of quarks

Comment: What is the difference between no quarks and no real quarks? If the quarks are fictional then beliefs about them are, strictly speaking, untrue, even if they are very useful fictions see [Fictionalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fictionalism/). And since this is an argument against scientific realism it has nothing to say about what to believe, that is determined by usefulness.

Comment: yeah i think i overstated my point @Conifold

Comment: why has been downvoted? i can't think of anything clearer, i've studied philosophy of science, based on the PMI, formally, and it's a novel question. you guys make me sick

Answer (score 1):

Here is the abstract to Larry Laudan's 1981 ***A Confutation of Convergent Realism***, which according to Wikipedia kicked-off the current notion of the pessimistic meta-induction:

> This essay contains a partial exploration of some key concepts associated with the epistemology of realist philosophies of science. It shows that neither reference nor approximate truth will do the explanatory jobs that realists expect of them. Equally, several widely-held realist theses about the nature of inter-theoretic relations and scientific progress are scrutinized and found wanting. Finally, it is argued that the history of science, far from confirming scientific realism, decisively confutes several extant versions of avowedly 'naturalistic' forms of scientific realism.
>
> [link](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/288975)

What is scientific realism?  According to the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy:

> Scientific realism is a positive epistemic attitude toward the content of our best theories and models, recommending belief in both observable and unobservable aspects of the world described by the sciences.
>
> [link](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-realism/)

Specifically, Laudan attacks scientific realism as being unsupported by either *reference* or *approximate truth*.  I suppose that when realism recommends belief in both observable and unobservable aspects of the world described by the sciences, it is not the observable aspects that Laudan opposes but the unobservable ones.

We will not learn from this whether Laudan is criticizing the truth-value of scientific theories or merely whatever mind-independent reality is contained by scientific theories; instead, we're talking primarily about belief.

***Belief in quarks***

So, under the pessimistic epistemic attitude, should we believe in quarks?  Of course we should believe in quarks!  Quarks are observable; it does not matter so much that they are only observable using the right equipment, or that they are only observable indirectly: their known qualities and interactions have been observed and reported to us by various scientists who we have no reason to doubt.

Only a great conspiracy of diverse individuals, unified in resolve, could have presented to the public today's knowledge of quarks without actually making the quark observations.  This hypothetical conspiracy fails under any ordinary examination, so belief in quarks is well-warranted.

Comment: as it doesn't answer the question, maybe you should delete it and edit the details into the question? just an idea

Comment: no worries at all! i often get indirect answers, which is frustrating, but not a nuisance at all :)

Comment: @confused, I made an edit in which I retract my admission that I'm not answering the question.  Instead, I'm explicitly forming this as a "frame challenge", which essentially concludes that we are not forced to choose between the two options given at first; a third option, that of critically choosing "belief" appears.

Comment: hm. do you have an antecedent for using "belief" like this? i'm not sure i understand suddenly

Comment: @confused, see my edit: I had brought the word "belief" over from the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy as a matter of due caution.

Comment: quarks are scientific unobservables right? i agree with the tenor tho

Comment: @confused, "quarks" have exactly the same epistemic value today that phlogiston and the humours had in their time.  The words summarize the real and valid observations of people who are looking into these matters, who say verifiable things about them in their professional literature.  Did "phlogiston" never exist?  No, phlogiston was the best explanation at the time; today, phlogiston could be well-defined by calling it an antiquated term encapsulating "heat of combustion" and "reduction potential" for the elements under study at the time.

Comment: @confused, in brief, Yes you should believe in quarks.  But No, that belief should be contained as much as possible by what's known about quarks.  Are they magical?  No.  But some are charmed!  Still not magical.  So should you believe that quarks are magical?  No.

Comment: It always puzzles me when idealists get together on the internet to talk about their shared skepticism of realism. Science gives us tools to conceptualise 'whatever this reality is'. And to predict how it might behave. The standard model is problematic.. but it's the best model we have so far.

Comment: @Richard, were you talking about Laudan's paper, @ confused 's question, my answer, or something else?

Comment: @elliotsvensson I was just commenting on the question generally.

Comment: For quarks you could substitute pianos. Being able to observe a phenomenon is not enough to prove realism or falsify idealism. This would be a task for metaphysics. Quarks may well exist in the same way as pianos and this is exactly what those who deny naive realism claim, that this form of existence is undeniable but not fundamental, merely appearances in consciousness. The physical sciences have nothing to say on this topic since they do not ask metaphysical questions or address them. .

Comment: @PeterJ, or statues!

Comment: @PeterJ, is it naive of me to think that the conflict is over scientific pronouncements over things that have not been observed or perhaps not been observed directly?  Seemingly a realist wants to grant scientists that authority, while an anti-realist does not.

Comment: @elliotsvensson - I feel if there is any naivety here it is in thinking that scientists have anything useful to say about these matters. It is not their job. What has been observed or not-observed is irrelevant to the debate since it is precisely the existential status of observed phenomena that is the issue being debated. Scientists do not look into this issue and have no way to do so. They tend to treat metaphysics as a matter of opinion, like politics, and just vote for what appeals to them.

Comment: PS - This is not to say that all scientists are bad philosopher but it's a rare conjunction when they're good at both. In my judgement no naive realist is a good philosopher since it's an idea that does not survive analysis.  .